# How to get data from a php page, using js without reloading

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, api

I'm trying to send a get request to a php page(for example: short.php) on my subdomain, from  a php page on my main domain( for example from index.php), and read data from that page and show it on index.php without reloading.
I want to do this using js, as im quite new to js I need help

You can use :
short.php→ http://api.i9i.xyz/?mod=wysbd&longurl=6283673

Comment: Clicking your link I get `https://i9i.xyz/3qoih` - why don't you rather show a [mcve] of what you have so far?

Comment: Google "AJAX Tutorial PHP" SO is not a tutorial site. Once you have a code related question come on back

Answer (score 1):

**AJAX**: Using the [Fetch API:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) *(non IE compatible)*

*index.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Fetch GET</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Welcome</h1>

  <script>
    fetch("simple.php").then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      console.log(data.message);
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

*simple.php*

```
<?php

  $data = [
    "message" => "Hello, World!"
  ];

  echo json_encode($data);
```

- Open terminal (from the folder you placed those two files) and run `php -S localhost:8080`
- In your browser head to `localhost:8080` (you should see "Welcome")
- Open Dev tools (hit <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- In the Console you should see `"Hello, World!"`

To make it apparent that no page refresh is happening, you could create a button, an on click go fetch the data:

```html
<h1 id="title">Welcome</h1>
<button id="btn" type="button">Get title</button>

<script>

    const EL_title = document.querySelector("#title");  
    const EL_btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

    EL_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      fetch("simple.php").then( res => res.json()).then(data => {
        EL_title.textContent = data.message;
      });            
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You should mention that `fetch` is only supported in *modern* browsers. For example, it will not work in any version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Booboo mentioned! Thank you. PS: for that matter Arrow functions will not work either, so... Yes, no IE. Update to Edge.

Comment: Thanks a lot! got a rough idea how to do it :p

Comment: I only mentioned Internet Explorer as a worst-case example. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API for browser support.